# How to convert mutiple json array to single json array

Tags: json

Iam getting json array like this

[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Diamond City Hotel
        )

```
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => Astera Sathorn
    )
```

How to convert this to single json like

Comment: single JSON like what? (whatever "single JSON" means...)

Comment: That looks like a PHP array printed via `print_r`